# Text from URL to String - C++

Tags: c++, string, url

What I want my program to do is to download data from URL(this will be some text, code, whatever) and save it to string in C++. How do I do this? I googled a lot and found absolutely nothing, except using some classes that exist only on Linux. I'm working on Windows so I don't accept answers such as: use curl.h . Thanks

Comment: What's your problme with using libcurl under Windows?

Answer (score 0):

There are some POCO libraries that make it very easy. Here is some code that reads a single line of text from a website:

```
#include "Poco/URIStreamOpener.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPStreamFactory.h"

Poco::Net::HTTPStreamFactory::registerFactory();
Poco::URIStreamOpener& opener = Poco::URIStreamOpener::defaultOpener();
try
{
    std::auto_ptr<std::istream> reader(opener.open(myURL));
    reader->getline(line,sizeof(line));
}
catch(...)
{
}
```

And that's all there is to it. The `try...catch` is there in case of a bad Internet connection.